# Using jQuery to check each div for element and apply "if" statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check the page and find the divs that do not have an image and change the class of an element within that div accordingly. The page is being dynamically generated so I need to check each element. The code itself works for affecting all the divs, but I need to check each one and only affect the ones with pictures.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container"><img width="695" height="519" src="pic123.jpg" /><div class="arrow"></div><!--arrow--></div><!--container-->
<div class="container"><div class="arrow"></div><!--arrow--></div><!--container-->
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
if ($(this).has("img")){
$('.arrow').addClass('classone');
};
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the if statement:

```
$(".container:has(img) .arrow").addClass("classone");
```

Or you can try this version:

```
$(".container").filter(":has(img)").find(".arrow").addClass("classone");
```

Comment: Works! Awesome! Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    if ($(this).has("img")){
        $('.arrow',this).addClass('classone');
    };
});
```

`$(this).find('.arrow').addClass('classone');` would work too

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, It should work fine If you just change

`$('.arrow').addClass('classone');`

to

`$('.arrow', this).addClass('classone');`

or Try using [.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) as below,

```
$('.container').has('img').find('arrow').addClass('classone');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
   if ($("img", this).length > 0){
      $('.arrow', this).addClass('classone');
   };
});
```